# Keycloak Not able to import realm

Tags: postgresql, azure, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

In my keycloak values.yaml I have mounted my realm and using a configmap for the same. But the error I see in my keycloak logs is -

```java
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_b71cjlbenv945rb6gcon438at"
  Detail: Key (realm_id, client_id)=(walter, account-console) already exists
```

And in my postgress logs in azure I see error -

```java
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_b71cjlbenv945rb6gcon438at"
2023-09-29 15:49:58 UTC-6516f21f.73e80-DETAIL:  Key (realm_id, client_id)=(walter, account-console) already exists.
2023-09-29 15:49:58 UTC-6516f21f.73e80-STATEMENT:  insert into public.CLIENT (ALWAYS_DISPLAY_IN_CONSOLE, BASE_URL, BEARER_ONLY, CLIENT_AUTHENTICATOR_TYPE, CLIENT_ID, CONSENT_REQUIRED, DESCRIPTION, DIRECT_ACCESS_GRANTS_ENABLED, ENABLED, FRONTCHANNEL_LOGOUT, FULL_SCOPE_ALLOWED, IMPLICIT_FLOW_ENABLED, MANAGEMENT_URL, NAME, NODE_REREG_TIMEOUT, NOT_BEFORE, PROTOCOL, PUBLIC_CLIENT, REALM_ID, REGISTRATION_TOKEN, ROOT_URL, SECRET, SERVICE_ACCOUNTS_ENABLED, STANDARD_FLOW_ENABLED, SURROGATE_AUTH_REQUIRED, ID) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26)
```

I checked my table in keycloak db there is no such record for realm "walter"

My `values.yml` file is

```yaml
    extraVolumes: |
      - name: realm-config
        configMap:
          name: realm-config
          defaultMode: 0755
      - name: keycloak-postgres-configuration-script
        configMap:
          name: keycloak-postgres-configuration-script
          defaultMode: 0755
    
    extraVolumeMounts: |
      - name: realm-config
        mountPath: "/realm/init-realm/"
    
    
    extraInitContainers: |
      - name: init-postgres-configuration
        image: postgres:12.11
        command:
          - /bin/bash
          - -c
          - |
            PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD psql -h $POSTGRES_HOST -p $POSTGRES_PORT -U $POSTGRES_USER -d $POSTGRES_DB -f /tmp/postgres-records.sql
        volumeMounts:
            - name: keycloak-postgres-configuration-script
              mountPath: /tmp
        env:
          - name: POSTGRES_HOST
            value: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
            value: "xxxxxx"
          - name: POSTGRES_PORT
            value: "5432"   
          - name: POSTGRES_USER
            value: "abc@xxxxxx"
          - name: POSTGRES_DB
            value: "abc_db" 
    
    extraEnv: |
      - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
        value: "true"
      - name: DB_VENDOR
        value: postgres
      - name: DB_ADDR
        value: "xxxxxxxxx"
      - name: DB_PORT
        value: "5432"
      - name: DB_DATABASE
        value: "xxxxxxx"
      - name: DB_USER
        value: "xxxxxxx"
      - name: DB_PASSWORD
        value: "xxxxxx"
      - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
        value: admin
      - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
        value: admin
      - name: KEYCLOAK_IMPORT
        value: /realm/init-realm/abc-realm.json
    
    postgresql:
      enabled: false
    
    ingress:
      .....
```

Comment: Show your file `values.yaml` .

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue ?  If yes, kindly post us the answer

Comment: @SathishKumar yeahh , posted it

Answer (score 0):

The above configuration is right, however when I was trying to create keycloak DB through extra init container, I saw in my Azure postgres that there were two authorizations happening and both trying to add the respective realm. So I  created a script to create keycloak DB and user. Before I install keycloak.

Also, while deploying keycloak and importing realm make sure -

- Your keycloak DB should be empty ( as even if the keycloak failed to
  import realm it creates respective tables and a few entries in them.
  They might block you)